# activeadmin access one resource's comments by two models rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancan

I have rails4 app. It has (among others) `Client` and `Developer` models. I also have `Submission` model.
I use [activeadmin](http://activeadmin.info/) with [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gems.
I try to make `Submission`'s comments to be visible for both `Client` and `Developer` (which are related to certain `submission`), but when I check, `developer` only sees his comments and `client` correspondingly his. Assume, it has something to do with `Ability` class definitions. Here is mine (partially):

```
 def developer_rules(developer)
    can [:read, :create], ActiveAdmin::Comment
 end

 def client_rules(client)
    can [:read, :create], ActiveAdmin::Comment
    can :manage, Client, id: client.id
 end
```

Has anyone faced anything similar? Would be grateful for any hints. Thank you!

UPD: SOLVED

Comment: cancan is dead. Use cancancan instead: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, issue has nothing to do with `Ability` class.
ActiveAdmin shows comments separately for every namespace (even though these comment are associated to same resource), therefore the solution is to override this method

```
def self.find_for_resource_in_namespace(resource, namespace)
  where resource_type: resource_type(resource),
  resource_id: resource_id_cast(resource),
  namespace: namespace.to_s
end
```

deleting last line `namespace: namespace.to_s` so that comments are shown independent of namespace.